# Create a slideshow with 5 images using ffmpeg with an output rate of 3 fps

Tags: image, ffmpeg, slideshow

I tried everything, so this is my last chance.

I need to make a slideshow using ffmpeg of the following files:
image-1.jpg
image-2.jpg
image-3.jpg
image-4.jpg
image-5.jpg

The input rate will be 1 fps (these are images so it's normal), but I would like the output rate to be 3 fps. Each image must last 1 minute for example.

My aim is to have the smallest output file size for this slideshow. I can use any codec I want.

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/30 -i image-%d.jpeg video.mpg
```

But ffmpeg says:

```
MPEG1/2 does not support 5/1 fps
```